# How to perform an explicit call to the built-in function chr() when the parameter 'needle' passed to the built-in function strpos() is not a string?

Tags: php, php-7.3

I'm using **PHP 7.3.4** on my home machine that runs on **Windows 10 Home Single Language 64-bit Operating System**

I've installed the latest version ox **XAMPP** installer on this machine.

Today, I come across the follwoing text from the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php#refsect1-function.strpos-parameters) :

> **needle**
>
> If **needle** is not a string, it is converted to an integer and
>   applied as the ordinal value of a character. This behavior is
>   deprecated as of PHP 7.3.0, and relying on it is highly discouraged.
>   Depending on the intended behavior, the **needle** should either be
>   explicitly cast to string, or an explicit call to **chr()** should be
>   performed.

From the above statement, I understood very well that if the parameter **'needle'** passed to the built-in function `strpos()` is not a **string** I have to explicitly cast it to **string** but I am not understanding how to perform an explicit call to the built-in function `chr()` when the parameter **'needle'** passed to the built-in function `strpos()` is not a **string**.

As I'm using the latest stable version of PHP i.e. **PHP 7.3.4**, I want the **working code example** specific to the **PHP 7.3.x** version which will demonstrate how the explicit call to the built in function `chr()` is performed when the parameter 'needle' passed to the built-in function `strpos()` is not a **string**.

It would be better if someone could also provide me the working code example that will demonstrate if the parameter **'needle'** passed to the built-in function `strpos()` is not a **string** how to explicitly cast it to **string**.

In short, I need two working code examples demonstrating the **manual text**.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$vs = [42, '42'];
foreach ($vs as $v) {
    var_dump(
        strpos('zz*z', is_string($v) ? $v : chr($v)),
        strpos('zz42z', (string)$v)
    );
}
```

Output:

```
int(2)       // chr of 42 is "*"
int(2)       // casting 42 to string gives you "42"
bool(false)  // There's no "42" in first string
int(2)       // casting string "42" to string still gives you a string "42"
```

In php7.2 and earlier:

```
var_dump(
    strpos('zz*z', 42),
    strpos('zz42z', 42)
);
```

Output:

```
int(2)        // 42 implicitly converted to "*"
bool(false)   // 42 implicitly converted to "*"
```

In php 7.3 you will get **same results**, but with warning:

> Deprecated: `strpos()`: Non-string needles will be interpreted as strings in the future. Use an explicit `chr()` call to preserve the current behavior in /.. on line ..

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you please also add the code which works with PHP versions before **PHP 7.3.0**? Thanks.

Comment: `strpos('zz*z', 42)`?